# Having problem with constructor code "error in student class"?

Tags: java, mysql, class, object, constructor

first i had make class and object in which i had call student name but when i had try to implement constructor i wouldn't working please suggest some solution regarding this code

Class object code:

```
package classObject;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class classObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        studentClass st=new studentClass();
}
}
```

Student class code:

```
package classObject;

public class studentClass {

    {
        String fname;
        String lname;
        static int count=0;

        public studentClass()
        {
            System.out.println("i m construtor");
        }



    void print ()
    {
        System.out.println(fname+" "+lname);
        count++;
        System.out.println("total student are= "+count);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your error? Remove the { right before your constructor. You are trying to declare your constructor inside a block

Comment: Isn't there an extra bracket in `studentClass`?

Comment: the indentation of the code should hint that there is a problem with brackets... (as should the compiler, despite it isn;t always understandable, but at least it should indicate where the problem is) Anyway you should stick with one way of writing the opening bracket, that is, always in the same line (fist class) **or (exclusive)** on a new line (second class, ignoring the wrong one)

Comment: If the file are not in the same folder probably you need to import the studentClass. I suggest to use a single file. There is an extra bracket "{" after studentClass declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove second { in studentClass.java, According to your code line number 5 **

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra opening curly brace just after the opening brace of the student class.